# unable to install scikit-earn on python 2.7.9 in Windows?

Tags: python-2.7, pip, scikit-learn

I have python 2.7.9 (which comes with pip already installed), I have numpy 1.8.2 and scipy 0.15.1 installed as well.
When I try to install scikit-learn, I get the following error

> > > pip install -U scikit-learn
> > >
> > > SyntaxError: invalid syntax

What am I doing wrong? 
Or is there another way to install scikit- learn on windows, if I can't use pip ?

Comment: try easy_install scikit-learn

Comment: Are you trying this inside python? This is a shell command.

Comment: It maybe worth looking at [anaconda](https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/) or [winpython](http://winpython.sourceforge.net/) which come with all this installed and doesn't mess up your current python environment

Answer (score 2):

I strongly suggest that since you are on Windows to use either [Anaconda](https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/) or [WinPython](http://winpython.sourceforge.net/) these are complete python environments with the full pydata stack preinstalled, they have numpy, scipy, sklearn, pandas, ipython etc.. They don't interfere with any current python installation and have package managers that allow you to upgrade relatively pain-free.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the directory worked in my case.
Suppose your python 2.7.9 is in C drive so you set you directory as follows and write your command like this : 
**C:\python27\scripts> pip install -U scikit-learn**